# How to send media files using firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a simple chat application in android, I found firebase cloud messaging using this I can send simple text messages, but I want to send media files like images, audio and video. Can I send media files using firebase cloud messaging? Is there any other free messaging server?

Comment: In general, you don't send (important) media files through push notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging limits you to 4K of data per message, which means you can't directly send media. You can include a URL in the message which your app can use to download the media.

Comment: for image,audio,video files i have to store it in firebase storage i need to send this url in json payload

Comment: @skyshine You can store the files anywhere in the web. You can include the url in the JSON "data" dictionary. For example - `{...,"data":{"url":"http://..."},...}`